# what's wrong in this LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, xpath, .net-3.5, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML

```
<School Version="30">
    <Math>
        <Lesson1 Type="Active">Introduction</Reset_mode>
        <Lesson2 Type="Active">Fundamentals</Reset_mode>         
    </Math>
</School>
```

I want to get the subelements lesson1, lesson2

I load the XML in XDocument

I have to question - what's wrong in this query

```
var nodes = from C in document.Element("School").Elements()
            where document.Element("School").Elements().Contains(t => t.Name == "Math")
            select C ; //shortcutsXMLDocument.SelectNodes(Query);
```

and it raise and error.

Also can I use XPath with XDocument?

Comment: "It raise error". Which error? Post the exception details please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a `ShortcutList` element :

```
Element("ShortcutList")
```

Which does not exists.

You should write this to get subLessons :

```
var items = document.Element("School").Element("Math").Elements();

foreach(var item in items)
{
    DoSomething(item);
}
```

Comment: how to get the childnodes in elements to be able to do XmlNode n = nodes[0].ChildNodes[i]; also can I use xpathes

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < nodes[0].ChildNodes.Count; i++){XmlNode n = nodes[0].ChildNodes[i];} it raise error how to do that

Comment: it raise error Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>'

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to XML:

```
 from subject in XDocument.Load(xml).Element("School").Elemens()
 where subject.Name == "Math"
 select subject.Elements();
```

XPath using XmlDocument:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("School/Math/Lesson1 or School/Math/Lesson2");
```

Comment: Can I perform xpath with xdocument, and how to get child nodes I nedd to for (int i = 0; i < nodes[0].ChildNodes.Count; i++){XmlNode n = nodes[0].ChildNodes[i];} it give error

Comment: it raise error Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>'

Comment: Of course you can use XPath with XElement/XDocument, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.extensions.aspx

Comment: @AMH: Don't use indexer. Use `First()` (will raise en exception if sequence contains no elements) or `FirstOrDefault()` (will return null in such case)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.Decendants("Math");
```

yields you a IEnumrable with your two elements. 
it's equal to the xpath //Math

Answer (score 0):

Xpath case used on XElement/XDocument from this namespace System.Xml.XPath.

here is your query for path...

var nodes = from C in document.XPathSelectElements("./Math")
            select C; //shortcutsXMLDocument.SelectNodes(Query);